# How to use DATEDIFF in Power Query (M query) to look for months between two dates

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I need to find the month difference between two dates (checkIn and Checkout dates) in Power Query (M-query). It can be similar to DAX bellow.

`period of months = DATEDIFF([dateCheckIn], [dateCheckOut], MONTH )`

I found the function
`daysDiff = each Duration.days([date1]-[date2])` 
but there is no function for month difference.

Comment: I think I got it. ((Date.Year([Change_Close_Date])-Date.Year([Change_Create_Date]))*12) + Date.Month([Change_Close_Date]) - Date.Month([Change_Create_Date])

Answer (score 7):

As a new user to Power BI I am finding the need to filter between DAX and Power Query answers to be tiresome! DAX has a DATEDIFF function and Power Query (the M language?) doesn't? Why not?

There is a [Duration function in M](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powerquery-m/duration-functions).

**But** that doesn't do months.

So I am grateful to you Thao N for asking and answering this question - a very neat line of code!

This is what you need:

```
((Date.Year([Change_Close_Date])-Date.Year([Change_Create_Date]))*12) + Date.Month([Change_Close_Date]) - Date.Month([Change_Create_Date])
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this (I calculate with half months). For full months use 30 and 1, for quarter months use 7.5 and 4.

```
Number.IntegerDivide(Duration.Days([End]-[Start]), 15)/2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula:

```
Date.Month(Date1)-Date.Month(Date2)+12*(Date.Year(Date1)-Date.Year(Date2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought this help me so if you like:

```
(12-Date.Month([StartDate])+1)+
(Date.Month([EndDate]))+
(((Date.Year([EndDate])-Date.Year([StartDate]))-1)*12)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use `Number.From(([Date1] - [Date2])/30)`.